# Replace input text with paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I have a basic color presentation using input texts and boxes using CSS, I achieve it only using input text as you can see into this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxqnH/30/), I want to do same with same adjust but without using input text, what I need to do to show only as a `<p>` tag

I try to replace input with paragraph tag but it disadjust like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxqnH/31/)

Help is very appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had added paddings to your input tags which you missed out when you converted them to paragraphs. 
So just add them to your paragraphs tags like this,

```
.input-color p {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

See **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gb25zy8/5/)**

If you still want them to have the text box like appearance you can just add background-color, border, and sufficient width, paddings and margins.

See **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gb25zy8/8/)**

Comment: Please mark as the right answer and upvote if this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the boxes, you can add this little snippet into your css

```
p.input{
  width: 150px;
  height:16px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

**You must have the paragraph have the class "input" and before your text for this to display correctly (of course someone else has something that would work)**. If you want the same color, use the hex: #111111 and it should be the same if not the exact color. Just to see this, here is my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zyz5vv9/)**